# Why are MakeHuman rigs' facial bones reversed?

Tags: bones, makehuman

I know that the hip bones can be reversed when importing MakeHuman files to Blender, but I haven't had that problem. I can't find any information about my issue on the internet at all. I've used MakeHuman and Blender for months without any problems, but when I reinstalled Ubuntu and opened a file created in my previous installation, all the facial bones of MakeHuman rigs are reversed. Ubuntu and Blender are the same versions as before. I only reinstalled Ubuntu so that I could use a different hard drive. I just copied Blender from one disk to the other and opened an old blend file in the new installation. This is what it looked like:

[image: rig with character]

[image: octahedral bones]

When I tab into Edit mode, the bones snap back to normal. This is what it looks like:

[image: everything's okay in edit mode]

[image: normal face]

[image: this is what the rig should look like]

The rig in these pictures was not exported from MakeHuman in my new installation. It was saved before I reinstalled Ubuntu. But I have also exported MakeHuman rigs in the new installation, and the results are the same. I appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you.

Comment: Click "rest Position" over under the Data drop down, under Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem just went away on its own, so I don't know how to explain it. After I tabbed back into Pose mode, the facial bones stayed the way they were supposed to, and the problem didn't happen again in any other files that I opened. If anyone else has this problem, please post a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered the same problem which you describe exactly. Same deformation, same face bones facing backwards. Reinstalled the operating system after some system trouble so everything was installed fresh. Then opening Blender models using MakeHuman generated figures in Blender 2.59a this problem pops up. Edit mode looks good, pose and object mode have the deformation. In some cases using pose -> clear transform all resets the figure back to the position in edit mode. Other cases, nothing changes. What's really puzzling is that the scene has 2 or 3 figures and it only happens on one or two, not all. My guess so far is some metadata outside the blend file was needed. Having wasted at least a day on this will reimport the Makehuman figures and move on. If a fix is found will update it here. Posting this in thanks to you that I'm not crazy and neither are you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. This problem disappears after also reinstalling MakeHuman and the addons for Blender relating to Makehuman. These can be found at http://www.makehumancommunity.org/content/plugins.html  In my case the makehuman objects which had been imported into blender had also been restored but not sure if this is needed to fix the problem. In any case Blender must be reaching out to something through Makehuman to render the objects correctly. For Chris since it was a clean rebuild MakeHuman was likely reinstalled which resolved the problem but there wasn't an immediate recognition that it fixed the distortion. The problem occurred since Blender was being used without Makehuman also being reinstalled from a bare disk system reinstall.